# Inflating child view controllers into fixed positions within parent

Tags: android, ios, swift, android-fragments

I want users to be able to click on different headings to show different segments of the screen.

The layout is like this:

[image]
By clicking on either `Heading_One` or `Heading_Two` will trigger a set of buttons to appear. In the app the user is presented with a set of half a dozen titles, each opening to dense functions/options for the user to use.

At the moment I'm inflating child view controllers through `addChildViewController` but I have to hardcode each `child view controller`'s position.

Is there a way to do this so it's like Android's fragment system? Thanks

Comment: To me it looks like you should use a collection view for what you're describing.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, how would I go about that?